# reindex api fails when shards have more then 2147483519 documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i had a elastic search index with 2 primary nodes hosted on on prem instances and one of the shard failed with following error :

```
failed shard on node [GK1he55KSJmqQXx-qDrPFQ]: shard failure, reason [no-op origin[PRIMARY] seq#[350554097] failed at document level], failure IllegalArgumentException[number of documents in the index cannot exceed 2147483519]
```

After searching a lot found only solution is to re index into new index with more shards or ILM in place. So i created new index with 4 shards and tried re indexing to that index.
the /reindex api gives following error

```json
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "Partial shards failure (1 shards unavailable)",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": []
    },
    "status": 503
}
```

Tried to search all forums how to handle this but nothing to avail. There no option to recover the current shard so do not suggest any recovery options.
i can handle some data loss but cannot discard the whole index (hence trying all recovery options)
below is my /reindex api :

```json
POST _reindex
{
   "conflicts":"proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "myindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_myindex"
  }
}
```

Comment: GET _cat/indices/myindex?v and check if the index is green?

Comment: It is red as 1 shard failed allocation.
Failed allocation is due to number of documents more than 2147483519

Comment: This is an older version than 7.10, which would contain a fix (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/63273), right? I thought that this should be recoverable (and then you could do a _split once the index is green). But if that does't work there is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-tool.html as a very last ressort.